# How to exclude a country in WooCommerce EU VAT

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've installed the 'WooCommerce EU VAT Number' for Wordpress. Currently it removes the VAT for every Country based in EU (as it should). My problem is that I need to make an exception for Denmark, which means that VAT should be imposed.

WooCommerce support can't help, but I found a code that does the exact opposite.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/eu-vat-number-2/?_ga=2.29124732.1928492864.1565251876-1046432304.1565251876#section-11

Would it be possible to reverse the effect of the code?

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_eu_vat_number_country_codes', 'woo_custom_eu_vat_number_country_codes' );`

`function woo_custom_eu_vat_number_country_codes( $vat_countries ) {
// only show field for users in DK
return array( 'DK' );
}`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Louis the code above only shows the VAT field for DK which is denmark? So are you saying you want to show VAT fields for all except Denmark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_eu_vat_number_country_codes', 'woo_custom_eu_vat_number_country_codes' );

function woo_custom_eu_vat_number_country_codes( $vat_countries ) {
// Remove field for Denmark.
if (($key = array_search('DK', $vat_countries)) !== false) {
unset($vat_countries[$key]);
}
return $vat_countries;
}
```

Please try the above if it doesn't work please try

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_eu_vat_number_country_codes', 'woo_custom_eu_vat_number_country_codes' );

function woo_custom_eu_vat_number_country_codes( $vat_countries ) {
echo "<pre>"; print_r($vat_countries); die('dead');
}
```

and paste the output here.